# Site loads very slow

Tags: magento2

When you go to my site https://www.uitverkoop.tips, it will take 10 seconds before you are on the site. How can this be?

When you are on the site, and you go to different page, it loads normal.

So where is the fault? How can I fix this? It is made in magento 2.

Comment: I'm getting 500 error in https://www.uitverkoop.tips/. Please add more information so that we can help you out. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean home page only takes more than 10 seconds?

Comment: All CSS and js are not loaded properly. https://prnt.sc/netsn6

Comment: Yes. Now all work well. I am back on Siteground. Errors and slow speed where on DomainRacer. Bad hosting.